# find min/max of date fields

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a database with multiple dates for the same unique ID. I am trying to find the first (min) and last (max) date for each unique ID. I want the result to be:
Unique ID, first Date, last date, field1, field2,field3

```
Select  max(date_Executed) as Last_Date,
    (select unique_ID, MIN(date_Executed)as First_Date
from Table_X
group by unique_ID, Field1, field2,field3
)
from Table_X
where unique_ID = unique_ID
group by unique_ID, Field1, field2,field3
order by unique_ID,First_Permit_Date
```

The error message I get is:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
>   Invalid column name 'First_Permit_Date'.

I’m new to SQL…
Thanks for your help-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why not a simple select with group by

```
Select  max(date_Executed) as Last_Date, MIN(date_Executed) as First_Date
from Table_X
group by unique_ID, Field1, field2,field3
order by unique_ID,First_Permit_Date
```

You can use more then one aggregation function ina select .. (with the same group by clause)

Comment: @Gross   . explain better you comment  .. you need some other support ..?

Comment: In case your date fields can be `null`, such as when `date_Executed` hasn't happened yet, and you want `null` to be the minimum value if it is present, you will need to do something like `min(isnull(date_Executed, convert(datetime, 0))) as First_Date`.

Comment: @KentWeigel   correct  .. if the value is null you can manage this way .. thanks

Comment: this answered my question. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it just be something like this?
I have no further insight in your tables, but the second 'select' statement seems to cause the error.

```
SELECT unique_ID, min(date_Executed) as First_Date, max(date_Executed) as Last_Date, field1, field2, field3

FROM Table_X
GROUP BY unique_ID, Field1, field2, field3
order by unique_ID, First_Permit_Date
```

Comment: I guess I was making it so difficult...! Thanks!